# How to insert multiple index at a time on a solr update using json

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have refer different related web page for getting how can i post multiple index to solr in a single request. I have gone through the solr link http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON#Example but the link explain feature not that much clearly.

Also i have found that create a json like this:

```
{
    "add": {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc1", "title" : "test1"} },
    "add": {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc2", "title" : "another test"} }
}
```

can solve the issue. But in this case only last index is updated/inserted to index. My project is a java project. Please help me on this.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code for generating this JSON and sending it to solr?

Comment: I am writing this as statically in order to check the solr. After getting the correct json structure i will create the json dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON module support using the regular JSON array notation (from 3.2 and forward). If you're adding documents, there is no need for the "add" key either:

```
[
  {
    "id" : "MyTestDocument",
    "title" : "This is just a test"
  },
  {
    "id" : "MyTestDocument2",
    "title" : "This is antoher test"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh this is working. But in my case i am planing to update index one by one. In this case i need to call 100 cron jobs if i need to update 100 users index. but in this case advantage is i can clearly track if there is any error up on indexing. When i submit index array as whole and if i catch any exception i only have response string but will not have any idea about from where the data getting error and what all data are indexed to solr. Bu if i call the update query one by one i can have a full control over all request and can update my db accordingly. Anyway thanks